# Avoid pdf and images from downloading

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have a web application where users can read some official documents and images. I want users to only view those documents and images, but prevent them from downloading. What should I do?

I am using carrierwave and ftp for file upload.

Comment: When you find a solution to this, don't forget to sell it to music & movie industry - they'll pay you in gold!

Comment: you can't. You should in that case create a desktop/mobile app, serve the content as encrypted data, and decrypt on the app

Answer (score 2):

When you sent something to a user to show it to them, all the data will go to their PC, and they will have full control over it. You cannot prevent someone (with knowledge of IT) from saving it.

You can try to make it a bit harder though, but never prevent it entirely.